# Are there any bonuses for using an authenticator with your Diablo III account?

Tags: diablo-iii

Attaching a [Blizzard Authenticator](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-authenticator-faq) to your Battle.NET account gave you some stupid Core Hound pet in *World of Warcraft*.  Other than the greatly enhanced security, are there any similar (trite, cosmetic) benefits in *Diablo III*?

Answer (score 2):

Not at this time.

At least I have not received any for my previously purchased authenticator (that I bought for WoW).

I should also note that the core hound I got for my authenticator in WoW was bind on account, so it was available across all of my WoW characters and their servers. If something were done in Diablo III, like the angel wings and dyes for purchasing the collector's edition, it would probably be the same way.

Answer (score 2):

As a person who has an authenticator attached to my account, I certainly haven't received anything. Authenticator's are a lot more common now that you can get it on your smart phone in app form, thus I think Blizzard isn't as likely to give out benefits.

Answer (score 0):

How about the benefit of not getting hacked?
I tried to go without it and I swear my account got hacked at least once a month.
I am kind of adverse to the idea (as I use the android app) because I re-flash my phone a lot and it is easy to forget to backup the app data. 
Now that they have implemented a restore key, I feel much better about it and I am using it.
Seriously.. Since D3 came out, my account has ALREADY been hacked. That was the last straw, seeing 2 characters on my account that I had not created and no one else has access to my account.

Comment: The asker specifically mentioned that he was asking for reasons 'other than the greatly enhanced security', and that's really the only reason you've listed here.  I think he's asking about bonus content, like the Core Hound pet he mentioned.

Comment: Sorry for not answering completely. Not at this time unfortunatly, however just the feeling of not having to worry about having to worry about lost items, characters and time is worth it all.